# Efficient way of traversing a complicated Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a database table that would return an array something like this

```
$roles['admin'] = 'app1,app2,app3';
$roles['moderator'] = 'app2,app3';
```

Now I want to traverse this array to show in my view, But instead of showing all apps inside each role, i would like to show all roles inside each app.

So ideally i would like the above array to become this

```
$apps['app1'] = 'admin';
$apps['app2'] = 'admin,moderator';
$apps['app3'] = 'admin,moderator';
```

I have been trying to solve this for 2 hours now, but for some reason I can't find an efficient way of doing this.

Comment: All your code does here is assign values to the array. What is the expected behavior? What would you *like* the code to do that it's not currently doing?

Comment: *"map"*, you want to map the array to a different form

Comment: wouldent a mult-d array be easier than string values coma deliminator?

Comment: i have edited my question

Comment: this is really not that hard with foreach and explode ...

Comment: well i did try it but soon it becomes a mess. i am looking for an efficient way

Comment: You should show what you tried that didn't work. [That way people know you did your homework and are more inclined to help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, and all codes were really good. But i think phil used php's built in functions to achieved this. Which according to my limited knowledge should be most efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map one array to the other by using [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-reduce.php), [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-keys.php) and [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/function.explode.php) to turn your CSV values into arrays

```
$apps = array_reduce(array_keys($roles), function($apps, $key) use ($roles) {
    foreach (explode(',', $roles[$key]) as $app) $apps[$app][] = $key; 
    return $apps;
}, []);
```

---

Note that the result is slightly different to what you wanted in that the values are themselves arrays instead of comma separated strings.

```
Array
(
    [app1] => Array
        (
            [0] => admin
        )

    [app2] => Array
        (
            [0] => admin
            [1] => moderator
        )

    [app3] => Array
        (
            [0] => admin
            [1] => moderator
        )

)
```

If you really need CSV values, add this

```
$apps = array_map(function($list) {
    return implode(',', $list);
}, $apps);
```

which produces

```
Array
(
    [app1] => admin
    [app2] => admin,moderator
    [app3] => admin,moderator
)
```

Comment: This is just perfect, thanks alot :)

Answer (score 2):

The following will traverse your array and load it into the appropriate array. It works by going through each part of the array and traversing it.

```
<?php
$apps = array();
foreach($roles as $key1 => $value1){
  $parts = explode(',', $value1);
  foreach($parts as $key2 => $value2){
   $apps[$value2] .= (strlen($apps[$value2])>0)?",":"").$key1;
  }
}
?>
```